# Can we find $| \langle x, y \rangle |$ for subgroups $\langle x \rangle$, $\langle y \rangle$ of a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know for subgroups $H,K$ of a group $G$, we have the following nice characterization:

$H \leq N_{G}(K)$ or $K \leq N_{G} H$, then $HK \leq G$.

The counting formula $|HK|= \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$ holds regardless.

I am trying to show that the size of the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ generated by $A= \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 \\
0 & \alpha^{-1} 
\end{pmatrix} $ and $B= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $ where $\alpha$ is a primitive $2n$-th root of unity is $4n$.

I was able to show that $|\langle A,B \rangle|=4n$ using the fact that this subgroup is isomorphic to $Q_{4n}$ since we have the relations $A^{2n}=1,\, A^{n}=B^2\,$ and $AB=BA^{-1}$. But is there a way to show this independently?

**Overall, do we have a characterization for when $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle$ for $x,y$ in an arbitrary group $G$?**

Comment: The complete list of elements of the group $\operatorname{gr}(A,B)$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha^k & 0\\
0 & \alpha^{-k}
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \alpha^k\\
-\alpha^{-k} & 0
\end{pmatrix}\mid k=0,1,\ldots,2n-1
\right\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. You can use the fact you mentioned. Since $BA=A^{-1}B$, it follows that $\langle A, B\rangle=\langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle$. Obviously we have $|\langle A\rangle \cap \langle B\rangle|=2$. Now use relations you found and the counting formula to show that $|AB|=4n$.

Edit.

It is not really clear what do you mean by "characterization", but if one able to show that $yx=x^ny$ for some $n$, then $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle$.

Comment: Perhaps the author meant the following problem:
Characterize groups in which for any two elements $x,y$ the equality $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle$ holds.